# Unable to make dynamic date filter work in crm analytics dashboard

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein-analytics-dashboards, tableau-crm, crm-analytics

I am working on crm analytics dashboard. I am working on a visualisation using the toggle method.
Wherein I can click on opportunities with close date as of this week, this month, this quarter and this year.
So that I if i click on Current week it filters all opportunities which have close date by end of this week.
I have tried several method to make this binding work. So far unable to do so. Kindly help.

This is my static box

```
"label": "Date2",
            "selectMode": "single",
            "type": "staticflex",
            "values": [
                {
                    "Display": "Current Week",
                    "Value2": "current day",
                    "Value3": "current day"
                },
                {
                    "Display": "Current Month",
                    "Value2": "current month",
                    "Value3": "current month"
                },
                {
                    "Display": "Current Quarter",
                    "Value2": "current quarter",
                    "Value3": "current quarter"
                },
                {
                    "Display": "Current Year",
                    "Value2": "current year",
                    "Value3": "current year"
                }
            ]
```

In query I added another filter using the above Date2 static filter - filter q by {{cell(Date2_1.selection, 0, ["Value2","Value3"]).asDateRange("date('CloseDate_Year', 'CloseDate_Month', 'CloseDate_Day')")}}

```
"query": "q = load \"Opps\";\nq = filter q by 'RR__c' == \"External\";\nq = filter q by 'StageName' in [\"Negotiating\", \"Opportunity Development\", \"Proposal Development\", \"Qualification\"];\nq = filter q by {{cell(Date2_1.selection, 0, [\"Value2\",\"Value3\"]).asDateRange(\"date('CloseDate_Year', 'CloseDate_Month', 'CloseDate_Day')\")}};\nq = group q by ('Name', 'Id', 'User.Id');\nq = foreach q generate q.'Name' as 'Name', q.'Id' as 'Id', q.'User.Id' as 'User.Id', sum(q.'Amount') as 'A';\nq = order q by 'A' desc;\nq = limit q 2000;\n"
```

But I am not sure, why the visualisation is not working in crm dashboard.

The error I get is
This widget can't be displayed because there is a problem with its source query:
cell(*, *, *).asDateRange("date('CloseDate_Year', 'CloseDate_Month', 'CloseDate_Day')")
**cell(Date2_1.selection, 0, [*, *])** => Invalid argument at index 2.

Can anyone help please.